# Why does Odata can't parse JSON when using Extend?

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using OData v4 in my project Web Api (.Net Core 3.1). I'm using Devart Linqconnect to generate my model. 
When I want to use "Extend" I'm getting message "can't parse JSON. Raw value". 
"Select" and "Filter" working good. I'm wondering why "Extend" not working properly.

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 2)]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Tasks_Object> query)
{

var items = query.ApplyTo(DBContext.Tasks_Objects.Where(i => i.Delete== null));

return Ok(items);
}
```

configuration of my controller/action in EDMModel.

```
var tasks_object = builder.EntitySet<Tasks_Object>("Task").EntityType.HasKey(e => e.ZAD_ID);

var task = builder.EntityType<Task>().HasKey(a=>a.ZAD_ID);
```

Comment: If you can share a minimal, reproducible example, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I have a large project and currently testing OData in this project. In another case when I created local data, "Extend" working good and I think it may be problem with Linqconnect which generate my model, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. 
"Extend" not working with LinqConnect because LQ using property EntitySet<> as a relation to other table, but we can change it.

There isn't problem with EF Core because EF Core using properties as a List<> not EntityRef.